# TimeSynchronizer (boost invalid initialization of reference)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have again a problem building the boost TimeSynchronizer Callback.
I hope you can help me :)

```
void callback (const ImageConstPtr& right, ImageConstPtr& left) {

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "stereo_vision");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> right_image(nh, "/stereo_camera/right/image_rect", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> left_image(nh, "/stereo_camera/left/image_rect", 1);

    TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image> sync(right_image, left_image, 10);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));


    ros::spin ();


    return 0;
}
```

The error msg:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >’
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61734/timesynchronizer-(boost-invalid-initialization-of-reference)/) by [Waterplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/4689/waterplant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-11-09**:
1.Did you add the required header files ?
2.Did you add boost libraries and linked them in the CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could it be that you are simply missing a `const` before `ImageConstPtr& left` in the arguments of your callback?

Best

Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2